# Calculate a point on a bounding box based on angle

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

OK. I suck at math!!

I have a situation where I would like to know the `(x,y)` position on a bounding square based on an angle.

The angle of 0 and 360 should be straight up.

Assuming we have a bounding square of (0,0 , 99,99) then an angle of 0 deg would return a point of (49,0)

An angle of 45 deg would return a point of (99,49)

180 deg would give (49, 99), 270 would give (0,49) and 360 would be back to (49,0)

I have NO clue how to calculate this. Any suggestions of where to read up on it so I can learn would be greatly appreciated.

Even better would be pseudo-code or even something in JavaScript.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Recently I just provide an ans for this question in C#, [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979673/how-to-get-random-points-from-a-box-collider2d/51980673#51980673).

Well, translate it into JS is not a difficult task.

```js
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");


var rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
var center = [rect.x + rect.width / 2.0, rect.y + rect.height/2.0]

function calCoor(theta, a, b)
{
    var rad = theta * Math.PI / 180.0;
    var x, y;
    var tan = Math.tan(rad);
    if (Math.abs(tan) > b/ a)
    {
        x = tan > 0 ? a : -a;
        y = b / tan;
    } else
    {
        x = a * tan;
        y = tan < 0 ? b : -b;
    }
    return [x,y]
}
var angle = 90;
var random_post = calCoor(angle, rect.width / 2.0, rect.height/2.0)

console.log("Angle at: " + angle)
console.log("x at: " + (random_post[0] + center[0]))
console.log("y at: " + (random_post[1] + center[1]))
```

```css
.square{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="myCanvas"></div>
```